# Best practice for transferring data from cross platform apps to server

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, rest, tcp

for some days me and my colleague are discussing whats the best practice for transferring data from **Android, iOS and Windows Phone 7 apps** to a windows server in the internet.

The apps on the different platforms should refresh (sync, get new data from server) each 5-10 seconds. The data which should be transferred has a size about 10kb (as plain text).

**Now our questions:**
What is the best practices to transfer this data? (TCP, REST, SOAP, HttpWebRequest??)

How to format the data? (XML, JSON??)

Comment: Data format depends on how you decide to use it and parse it.

Comment: depending on the format I would prefer JSON over XML. In Android you can use GSON lib to directly map that JSON inside an Object structure, while they are at least Dictionarys at IOS and WP7. At least its much slimmer than XML

Comment: Yes but there are different data types and especially on mobile devices with limited bandwidth its important to carry about size, etc..

Comment: thats why You should use JSON... the data size is smaller as I already said, while parsing is (at least most of the time) faster.

Comment: Refreshing every 10 seconds seems like overkill to me

Comment: @oneilse14: agreed. Imagine you have 200k apps running. That's 200k requests ever 5 seconds, or roughly 40,000 requests per second you need to handle, with a conservative estimate of running apps.

Comment: Its difficult to estimate the requests/second because its depends on the users activity. In the broader sense its a "chat". The users of a group will be notified if other user of this group posted something and request all posts (from the own group) since the last update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot depends on the nature of your application.

The easiest is JSON through a REST interface.

Using HTTP(REST) gives you a number of advantages, one of which that often is overlooked is ease of debugging (setup fiddler as an HTTP proxy).

Unless you need schema validation, there really isn't much of a reason to choose XML over JSON. All platforms have simple json parsing frameworks.